# Append strings into Pandas dataframe gives no result

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, error-handling

I have a dataframe using Pandas with transaction data, it looks something like this.

```
"Transactions",                 "State in transaction"
"Company name, Florida",         "N/A"
"Company name, California",      "N/A"
"Company name, Mississipi",      "N/A"
"Company name",                  "N/A"
             .                           .
             .                           .
             .                           .
```

And so on... I also have a data frame with states for both US and Canada. It looks something like this:

```
"Alberta"
"British Columbia"
"Manitoba"
    .
    .
    .
```

How can I insert it if state is in transaction, then it should give something like this (and stays with N/A if state not found in transaction):

```
"Transactions",                  "State in transaction"
"Company name, Florida",         "Florida"
"Company name, California",      "California"
"Company name, Mississipi",      "Mississipi"
"Company name",                  "N/A"
             .                           .
             .                           .
             .                           .
```

Currently I have tried:

```
for i, transaction in enumerate(df["Transactions"]):
    for state in df_states:
        if state in transaction
            df["State in transaction"].append(state)
            break
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.extract()`. Also, I am assuming your column names have quotes in my reproducible code below. The quotes in the column names / values make it a little bit messier. Do you have actual quotes in your data?:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Transactions': {0: 'Company name, Florida',
  1: 'Company name, California',
  2: 'Company name, Mississipi',
  3: 'Company name'}})
df['State in transaction'] = df['Transactions'].str.extract(', (\w+)').fillna('N/A')
df

Out[1]: 
               Transactions State in transaction
0     Company name, Florida              Florida
1  Company name, California           California
2  Company name, Mississipi           Mississipi
3              Company name                  N/A
```

Comment: Sorry, misread, no I dont actually have quotes in the data. Im not sure how to reproduce this. I have about 1300 transactions and I was thinking something like for each transaction, find a match in the state data frame.

Comment: There are thousands of different company names - does this still work?

Comment: Sort of worked - sorry if I have been unprecise, but the state is not always located at the same place and it is not comma separated (was just an example). It could look something like: Amaz#on/Street name#State 40359232FK

Comment: Hence, why I wish to take match by looking through the entire transaction data and every state in the data frame